# Replace browser history.state by NavigationManager.LocationChanged event with blazor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm working with blazor server-side app. I want to store an object on the browser history state just before it navigate to a different route. I'm using following code.

```
protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    NavigationManager.LocationChanged += OnLocationChanged;
}


private void OnLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs args)
{
    base.InvokeAsync(async () =>
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("updateState", myObject);
    });
}

public void Dispose()
{
    NavigationManager.LocationChanged -= OnLocationChanged;
}
```

following is the JavaScript function.

```
function updateState(myObject) {
    window.history.replaceState({ stateObj: myObject}, "");
}
```

I'm trying to read the history state when it navigate back. but I'm getting `window.history.state` as `null`. what I'm missing?

Comment: Hi @AnC Dev, how and where do you set `window.history.state` before your replace it?

Comment: Only invoke `window.history.replaceState`  when `OnLocationChanged` called. No any other set methods.